# Python: How to choose one of multiple scripts as a package to import into a main script, when located in different directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, python-import

I have multiple projects that all need a common script (`main.py`), but I need them to have different functions available that are specific to each project. This means that when I run the script for use in Project A, I want to be able to import its `configA.py`, but to import `configB.py` when running it for Project B.

For example, say that within both `configA.py` and `configB.py`, there is a different definition of the same function `foo()`. My goal is to be able to run something along the lines of `python3 main.py ../../ProjectA/Config/configA.py` for Project A, and similar for B. Then inside `main.py`, the script would import the file passed to it (something like `config = import_module(sys.argv[0])`), and then be able to run `config.foo()`, which would behave differently depending on which file was passed.

From reading a number of help posts on SO, I've seen many people suggest `importlib.import_module()`, since I can pass the package name as an argument to `main.py`. But the slight complication compared to these other posts I've read is to do with my file structure. It seems like `import_module()` only really works when the the main/package files are in the same directory, or when the main script is in a parent directory of the package. However, my file structure looks like this:

```
└─ Documents
   ├─ Common
   │  └─ Scripts
   │     └─ main.py
   ├─ ProjectA
   │  └─ Config
   │     └─ configA.py
   └─ ProjectB
      └─ Config
         └─ configB.py
```

Is there a way for me to be able to import the package of my choice for use in `main.py` given this file structure?

Comment: It is not clear where you want to import what. Please show some example (pseudo) code for that. How are you going to interact with `main.py`? What are the criteria for distinguishing between `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`?

Comment: Okay, I've added this to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if statement for the different imports:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.abspath('../..'))  # this is important so the packages are on the path

if sys.argv[1] == 'A':
    from ProjectA.Config.configA import foo
elif sys.argv[1] == 'B':
    from ProjectB.Config.configB import foo
else:
    raise ImportError(f'No module corresponding to {sys.argv[1]}')
```

Or you can use also use `importlib.import_module` instead of the `if/else` chain:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('Project{x}.Config.config{x}'.format(x=sys.argv[1]))
foo = module.foo
```

And then use via

```
python main.py A  # use foo from configA
python main.py B  # use foo from ConfigB
```

### Run via `-m` from `Documents`

An alternative to modifying `sys.path` is to run the `main.py` via the `-m` switch from within the `Documents` directory. When running `python main.py` then the script's directory will be put on the path. When running `python -m Common.Scripts.main` then the current working directory will be put on the path and hence `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` are automatically discoverable:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/Documents
$ python -m Common.Scripts.main
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I guess that `sys.path.insert()` is to do with the directory where the python command is run from?If this is the case, I hoped that if I were to navigate to `Documents/ProjectA/config/` and then ran `python3 ../../Common/Scripts/main.py configA`, that it would work with `module = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1])` in `main.py`. But this doesn't seem to work (it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configA'`)?

Comment: It doesn't work like that because when you run `python /path/to/script.py` then that script's directory will be put on the path, not your current working directory; i.e. in that case `/path/to`. So you can manually insert `/path/to/Documents` in `sys.path` and use imports from there. Or you run via the `-m` switch which will put your cwd on the path.

Comment: Ok, I have an idea for how I can do this now, thanks!

Comment: Update: it turns out the thing I tried above (running `python3 ../../Common/Scripts/main.py configA` from `Documents/ProjectA/config/`) actually did work, I had just misnamed `configA.py` as `configA,py`.

Comment: Yes in case there are no name clashes between modules it works too. The script's directory is the first `path` entry, the cwd is located behind.